# Change model attributes labels

Tags: php, yii

I have a model class, and i use it in many views.

```
class Translations extends CActiveRecord
{
...
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'row_id' => 'Row',
            'locale' => 'Locale',
            'short_title' => 'Short Title',
            'title' => 'Title',
            'sub_title' => 'Sub Title',
            'description' => 'Description',
            'content1' => 'Content1',
            'content2' => 'Content2',
            'com_text1' => 'Com Text1',
            'com_text2' => 'Com Text2',
            'com_text3' => 'Com Text3',
            'com_text4' => 'Com Text4',
            'com_text5' => 'Com Text5',
            'com_text6' => 'Com Text6',         
        );
    }
...
}
```

Can i change model attributes labels value for each view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could declare a scenario for the model depending on which view you are going to use and define the params according to the scenario? Lets say your different views are for different people:

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    switch($this->scenario)
    {
        case 'PersonA':
            $labels = array(
                ...
                'myField' => 'My Label for PersonA',
               ...
            );
            break;
        case 'PersonB':
            $labels = array(
                ...
                'myField' => 'My Label for PersonB',
               ...
            );
            break;
        case 'PersonC':
            $labels = array(
                ...
                'myField' => 'My Label for PersonC',
               ...
            );
            break;
    }
    return $labels;
}
```

Then in your controller for each person you can define the scenario, eg;

```
$this->scenario = 'PersonA';
```

Then in the view after declaring 'PersonA' as the scenario you'd see the label for `myField` as 'My Label for PersonA'

Comment: `switch` can be replaced with structure `array[scenario][label]`

Answer (score 0):

There is no method or variables that allow you change attributes labels in official way, so I would suggest you extend the Model to support it.

In CActiveRecord you could define a field named attributeLabels and method named setAttributeLabels and overrides the attributeLabels method.

```
protected $attributeLabels = [];

public function setAttributeLabels($attributeLabels = []){
    $this->attributeLabels = $attributeLabels;
}

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function attributeLabels(){
    return array_merge(parent::attributeLabels(), $this->attributeLabels);
}
```

and from the doc of \yii\base\Model::attributeLabels it says

> Note, in order to inherit labels defined in the parent class, a child class needs to merge the parent labels with child labels using functions such as `array_merge()`.

so in Translations class you should merge attribute labels from parent and so as the CActiveRecord class. So the CActiveRecord attributeLabels method should be like this:

```
public function attributeLabels(){
    return array_merge([
        'row_id' => 'Row',
        'locale' => 'Locale',
        'short_title' => 'Short Title',
        'title' => 'Title',
        'sub_title' => 'Sub Title',
        'description' => 'Description',
        'content1' => 'Content1',
        'content2' => 'Content2',
        'com_text1' => 'Com Text1',
        'com_text2' => 'Com Text2',
        'com_text3' => 'Com Text3',
        'com_text4' => 'Com Text4',
        'com_text5' => 'Com Text5',
        'com_text6' => 'Com Text6',
    ], parent::attributeLabels());
}
```